# Is a coroutine a kind of thread that is managed by the user-program itself (rather than managed by the kernel)?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, kernel, scheduler, coroutine

In my opinion,

**Kernel** is an alias for a running program whose program text is in the kernel area and can access all memory spaces;

**Process** is an alias for a running program whose program  has an independent memory space in the user memory area. Which process can get the use of the CPU is completely managed by the kernel;

**Thread** is an alias for a running program whose program-text is in the memory space of a process and completely shares the memory space with another thread of the same process. Which thread can get the use of the CPU is completely managed by the kernel;

**Coroutine** is an alias for a running program whose program-text is in the memory space of a process.And it is a user thread that the process decides itself (not the kernel) how to use, and the kernel is only responsible for allocating CPU resources to the process.

Since the process itself has no right to schedule like the kernel, the coroutine can only be concurrent but not parallel.

Am I correct in saying Above?

Comment: No, it is not a thread, it is another piece of code whose execution alternates with this one.

Answer (score 2):

> process is an alias for a running program...

The modern way to think of a process is to think of it as a container for a collection of threads and the resources that those threads need to execute.

Every process (except for "zombie" processes that can exist in some systems) must have at least one thread. It also has a virtual address space, open file handles, and maybe sockets and other resources that are shared by the threads.

> Thread is an alias for a running program...

The problem with saying that is, "running program" sounds too much like "process," and a thread is most definitely *not* a process. (E.g., a thread can only exist *in* a process.)

A computer scientist might tell you that a thread is one particular *execution* of the application's code. I like to think of a thread as an independent *agent* who executes the code.

> coroutine...is a user thread...

I'm going to mostly leave that one alone. "Coroutine" seems to mean something different from the highly formalized, and not particularly useful coroutines that I learned about more than forty years ago. What people call "coroutines" today seem to have somewhat in common with what I call "green threads," but there are details of how and when and why they are used that I don't yet understand.

*Green threads* (a.k.a., "user mode threads") simply are threads that the kernel doesn't know about. They are pretty much just like the threads that the kernel *does* know about except, the kernel scheduler never preempts them because, Duh! it doesn't know about them. Context switches between green threads can only happen at specific points where the application allows it (e.g., by calling a `yield()` function or, by calling some library function that is a documented *yield point.*)

> kernel is an alias for a running program...

The kernel also is most definitely not a process.

I don't know every detail about every operating system, but the bulk of kernel code does not run independently of the applications that the kernel serves. It only runs when an application thread *enters kernel mode* by making a system call. The thread that runs the kernel code still belongs to the application process, but the code that determines the thread's behavior at that point is written or chosen by the kernel developers, not by the application developers.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed, many thanks.By the way, I heard some one say this: thread is an independent task in Linux.I don't know if that description is correct....

Comment: @YeJun, I don't know that "task" has any special meaning in Linux. FYI: when they added multi-threading to Linux, they did it by extending the data structures that keep track of processes. We normally think of threads within a process, but in Linux they originally were _implemented_ as separate processes that all share the same address space, the same file handles, etc. I'm less interested in details of Linux today than I was back when that happened, so I'm not sure if it's still true today.